# How can a QWidget get the "entire" parent?

Tags: c++, qt

I have instantiated a widgetClass in MainWindow.cpp.  I want to pass in "this" to this widget as more than just (QWidget* parent) but also (MainWindow* parent).  But on the build, the widgetClass is established before the MainWindow and so it errors out.

I want to get to instanceVariables in the MainWindow??

ie:

```
myWidget(QWidget* parent, MainWindow* parent);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that i understood correctly, please rephrase the question if i didn't, but i think you need the setCentralWidget member function of your QMainWidndow derived class: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget , QMainWindow already has a layout and that's why you need to put your widget as the centralWidget.

Comment: In the other case (the things you said about the access to mainwindow functionality) you don't need to pass the MainWindow pointer, just code signals and slots for the functionality you need in both MainWindow and widgetClass and connect those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues on such task.. Maybe the problem is that you have to use [Forward Declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) to include one class in one other that include the first ones.. Or maybe the fact the default constructor of `QWidget` has the first argument as the default parameter.. what is your error exactly?

Anyway, here is a complete example:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mywidget.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    int foo(int n);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    MyWidget *w;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    w = new MyWidget(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(w);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

int MainWindow::foo(int n)
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    return n+42;
}
```

mywidget.h

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class MainWindow;

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(MainWindow *main, QWidget *parent = 0);
signals:
public slots:
};

#endif // MYWIDGET_H
```

mywidget.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

MyWidget::MyWidget(MainWindow *main, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    std::cout << main->foo(0) << std::endl;
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Not sure where MyWidget is being passed in the parent?  The rest seems to flow.

Comment: in MyWindget you have a reference of MainWindow as *main, and you can call a specific method of MainWindow (`foo`). In MainWindow you have an instance of MyWidget as *q.. Parent is not really touched, it is authomatically set by `setCentralWidget`..

Answer (score 1):

The [answer proposed by nkint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17710379/1951907) is the cleanest way to do. However, there exist quick hacks if you don't have time or can't change the architecture of your software:

If you *know for sure* that the parent of `MyWidget` is a `QMainWindow`, you can simply do:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QMainWindow * main = static_cast<QMainWindow*>(parent);
    std::cout << main->foo(0) << std::endl;
}
```

If you are not sure, i.e. may or may not actually be a `QMainWindow`, then you can do:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QMainWindow * main = qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>(parent);
    // here, main is null if and only if parent was not a QMainWindow
    if(main)
        std::cout << main->foo(0) << std::endl;
}
```

`qobject_cast` is similar to `dynamic_cast`. More precisely, the documentation says:

> The qobject_cast() function behaves similarly to the standard C++ dynamic_cast(), with the advantages that it doesn't require RTTI support and it works across dynamic library boundaries.
>
> qobject_cast() can also be used in conjunction with interfaces; see the Plug & Paint example for details.
>
> **Warning**: If T isn't declared with the Q_OBJECT macro, this function's return value is undefined.